# Will i compromise the structural integrity of my I-joist if i hang two 4×8 garage storage racks

Tags: structural, joists, load-bearing, engineering

[image]I am looking to install two 4x8 overhead storage racks in my garage. Will I compromise the structural integrity of my i-joist, that is, 2"wide × 1 3/8"high × 3/4" to the web if I drill vertically through the flange with a 5/16"×3" Lag Bolt that came with the racks? From what i know the top part of the I-joist is compressed while the bottom is under tension and I can't seem to find any answers on the internet, except when it comes to drill through the web. It's also a 2 story home.

Comment: I presume this is a wood I-Joist? Who made it, for that matter?

Comment: Correct its wood. Not sure. On it is written Trus Joist

Comment: Knowing how an I joist is made, I’m pretty sure the answer is no. But reach out to some manufacturers and ask them.

Comment: Wouldn't he want to contact the manufacturer of the I-joist instead of "some manufacturers?"

Comment: @RetiredATC I've added a picture to my post above

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Please see the pic that I added above. Thanks

Comment: @Elvis (great username BTW!) Thanks for the picture. From the technical specs (below) from your I-joist manufacturer I'd be really hesitant in drilling those holes without getting a go-ahead from TJI. The upper and lower flanges carry a lot of load. Maybe drilling is ok, but maybe not. TJI has phone support. I can't embed a link in a comment, but here's the web address: https://www.weyerhaeuser.com/woodproducts/engineered-lumber/resources/trus-joist-support/

Comment: @RetiredATC thank you. I will contact them as advised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.fp-supply.com/cmss_files/imagelibrary/I%2520Joists/Allowable-Holes-I-Joists--amp--Beams.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwje3-ez1an5AhXMKkQIHdt-CEwQFnoECCUQAQ&usg=AOvVaw3D9RPIx7W_EJq5U4jMWX3S) publication from TJI it tells you where you can drill and cut the I-joist web. In bold letters it days **DO NOT cut flanges.**

Comment: Informative, but the OP is asking about hanging a load from the flange.

Comment: I believe he is asking if he can drill through the flange, although maybe I misread it.

Comment: Agree, but drilling into the flange and loading it is different from cutting the flange.

Comment: @Aloysius Defenestrate You may be correct. The technical publication has holes in various places of various shapes and groupings in the web of the I-joist. There are no holes in the flanges. An additional note says to not cut or notch the flanges. Based on that, I would not drill a hole in the flange without consulting TJI first. Maybe I'm being too cautious, but the manufacturer is still in business and can be contacted for technical support. What's the downside?